# Best way to check if data is present on few servers

Tags: powershell, ssis

I'm looking for best solution to manage a task of checking if data is present on the server(s) and make a report out of the collected data.
As for now my solution is:

1. Powershell script to check if data is present on the server
2. Gather data from point 1 in .txt file
3. Read .txt file into Integration Services and load it to database
4. Create report in excel or something similar.

Would you recommend different approach? If so what would be this approach?
Regards

Comment: What "data"? In a file? The registry? A database?

Comment: PLEASE, read the Tour for this site & then answer ... where is your code? what did not work as intended?

Answer (score 0):

If it's file or directory you can do for file

```
$neededFile = "\\SERVER01\C$\file.txt"
if (Test-Path  $neededFile -PathType leaf) {
    Write-Output "File Exist"
    $fileContent = Get-Content $fileToCheck # Put in var $fileContent content of file
}
```

And for folder

```
$isFolderAlive = (Test-Path $path)
if ($isFolderAlive -eq "True") { 
    Write-Output "Directory Exist"
} else {
    Write-Output "Directory Does NOT Exist"
}
```